# Shortcut icon takes wrong image size on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-launcher, galaxy-nexus

I tried creating an app which puts a shortcut icon on the home screen of the device.

It works nice on other devices, but on my Galaxy Nexus (with 4.2.1) the icon crops the icon image and takes the top left of it only.

It appears like this:

[image]

Any idea why this might be happening, or is it a bug?

Comment: Just curious, is your icon in `drawable-xhdpi`?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with a custom ROM.

Handle this case and put another shortcut icon to Galaxy Nexus (with 4.2.1)

Comment: I have the stock Android in my phone, not a custom ROM. The icons which the system puts automatically on App Install appear fine, but from the code, they appear differently

Comment: Which icon size is apt for Galaxy Nexus, any idea? As per Android docs, it requires 96x96 but we're using 72x72 as of now. Any ideas?

Comment: Try 92x92 but change aligment inside

Comment: umm.. how to do that? (change alignment) ?

Comment: Alignment of your items in icon. From center to top right(For example)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22500/discussion-between-sheikh-aman-and-yahor10)

Answer (score 0):

Try delete all the icons except the one for the galaxy nexus(if i remember good it's 96X96)